# Omniauth and Foursquare not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, foursquare

So I'm using Omniauth to authenticate with the likes of Twitter and Foursquare. Twitter works fine, but Foursquare doesn't appear to return a secret.

Anyone know what's going wrong?

Here's the create action in the controller, Foursquare is passing the user back to this, but as I said, it's not getting the secret, just the token

```
def create
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    unless current_user.authentications.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
      current_user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
      current_user.save
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Authentication Successfull"
    redirect_to authentications_url
  end
```

Here is the apply omniauth method:

```
  def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
    authentications.build(
      :provider => omniauth['provider'],
      :uid => omniauth['uid'],
      :token => omniauth['credentials']['token'],
      :secret => omniauth['credentials']['secret']  
    )
  end
```

Comment: Done. Didn't think it was necessary as it's basic code and Twitter is working fine with this.

Comment: It's very difficult to diagnose without your omniauth version, and the error code you're getting.

Comment: Latest Omniauth, 2.0.1 I believe. That's the point, I'm not getting an error code though. Foursquare says it's worked fine, Omniauth says it worked fine, but the auth secret isn't being passed back.

Answer (score 0):

Foursquare should not pass back a secret, just the token. The foursquare api key and and secret are provided to you by foursquare when you register your app on their developers site. You must use these values in your omniauth.rb

Answer (score 0):

Twitter uses Oauth 1.0 and foursquare uses 2.0

That could be your issue there